# Program will not recognize device as iPad when I run simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad

I would like to load a different viewcontroller when the device running my app is an iPad, and would like to test it out in the simulator (obviously).  I have looked up online how to supposedly determine if the device running the app is an iPad, but it doesn't seem to be working.  Examples below.

When I set the device to iPad in Xcode and run it, the following code (in my appdelegate.m file) should print "recognized as ipad!" in the log, but does not:

```
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad){
    NSLog(@"recongnized as ipad!");
}
```

Secondly, I have a bit of code that prints the height of the device being used (again in my appdelegate.m file)

```
CGSize iOSDeviceScreenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
NSLog(@"device height is %f", iOSDeviceScreenSize.height);
```

However, when setting the device to iPad it says the height is 480, this is the height of the iPhone 4, not an iPad.  What am I doing wrong?  I just want to write an if statement in my appdelegate.m file that launches a different viewcontroller if the device is an iPad!  Thanks!

Comment: Is your app setup as an iPhone-only app, an iPad-only app, or as a universal app?

Comment: I think you need run iPad emulator instead iPhone.

Comment: @rmaddy Dude, that was it! My targeted device under build settings was set to only iPhone, I switched it to iPhone/iPad!  Thank you! stack overflow is just the best thing on earth

Answer (score 0):

`UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad` does not return `YES` if you run an iPhone-only app on an iPad, so it has to be at an universal app. However, it is the recommended way to distinguish between an iPad and the rest. There should be no good reason why you would want to check for iPad if your app is iPhone-only.

If you really want this to work without making your app universal, maybe for testing purposes, you could use the following string and see if it contains `"iPad"`:

```
    NSString *device = [[UIDevice currentDevice] model];
```

Keep in mind that this approach can break if Apple decides to change the model string. So I don't recommend using it if you decide to submit your app.